# Samsung a71 virus detected

Tags: samsung

so uh, i just went onto a website, and I apparently have 4 viruses on my phone, it said "Your sim card has been damaged by a virus!" I dont know if this is fr and I'm only 14, but i know when not to click on something stupid. But I have to ask, is this real? I know how to deal with it if it IS true, but it is weird. It says my sim card is already 48% damaged.

Comment: *i just went onto a website* → 100% scam. Close immediately and you'll have nothing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to the Internet. You will find web-sites telling you that you are the most intelligent person of the world and then they want to sell you something or they try to steal something from you. Therefore if a web-site claims something be distrustful and first start thinking if this can be really true - e.g. a if a web-site can really scan your device...

Answer (score 2):

The comments on your question already cleared things for you. It is [a scam](https://www.google.com/search?gl=us&hl=en&pws=0&filter=0&q=Your+sim+card+has+been+damaged+by+a+virus&gl=us&hl=en&pws=0&tbm=isch). If a website or an app suddenly or  ever claims that *something is wrong* with your device, its accessories, its OS, a web account, your bank account, **you can be damn well sure that the other  party is trying to scam you**.

10/10 times these scams appear as ads, so using an adblocker for both your web browser and and your device is suggested. I use [Ublock Origin addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/ublock-origin/) (on Firefox for Android) which greatly helps in reducing ads nonsense when browsing. To stop nonsense ads on Android apps I use [AdAway](https://adaway.org/) (you can also use [Blockada](https://blokada.org/)) adblocker app. Some folks give moral reasons not to use adblockers but I keep security, privacy and web sanity over morality. You are on your own with morality here.

In a browser, 9/10 times these ads are able to load through [javascripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/What_is_JavaScript), often third-party scripts. Using a solution which blocks at least third-party javascripts is recommended to everyone for browsing the web with sanity. I use [NoScript addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/noscript/) (on Firefox for Android).

You also need to know about WAP billing frauds (you click something on some [often] not-so-popular webpage, and guess what XY amount of money is automatically deducted by your carrier. You apparently gets subscribed to some XYZ value-added service!). WAP billing frauds are facilitated by third-party javascripts.

The list can go on but it is best that at this age you spend a couple of hours to learn about privacy and security on the web, Android or whatever OS your mobile and PC are using, on at least a monthly basis. What you would learn would be far better than a quick fix I have suggested.

Answer (score -2):

You can check any unknown apps is installed remove it.
Clear cache of web browser.

You can scan your mobile using antivirus. You can use avg, Avast or panda antivirus. You can use free trail of anti virus.

You can erase your mobile.